# Exchange DAG seeding operation fails with I/O error

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

we are getting below error on some of our database wheh we try to create/update a database copy:

The seeding operation failed. Error: An error occurred while performing the seed operation. Error: An error occurred while processing a request on server 'EX1-Server'. Error: An I/O error occurred while attempting to access file 'D:\Exchange\DAGMBDB01\Database\DAGMBDB01.edb' on source server EX1-SERVER. Error: EseDatabaseBackupReader: PerformDatabaseRead failed with error code 0xFFFFFC06. Expected 1048576 bytes read, but actually only 0 were read.

The disk are brand new ssd so it cant be a disk issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: **The disk are brand new ssd so it cant be a disk issue** - How did you confirm that? Also, do you have the appropriate AV exclusions configured for Exchange?

Comment: Because we replaced the disk after we started getting the error. Getting same error on new disk. We have AV exclusion also tried removing AV completely.

Comment: How many copies for this database? Did other copy in other disk work normally?

Comment: One active one passive. Active working fine just passive copy causing issue.

Comment: Did you create a new copy in the new disk instead of replacing the disk?

Comment: Yes so after replacing the disk I tried to create the copy. It didn't work. One thing I noticed is if the database size is small eg:  under 500GB it works. When database size is large eg 1TB roughly it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server Exchange Server 2016 Standard Edition? If yes, this issue occurs because the default database size limit for Exchange Server 2016 Standard Edition is 1,024 gigabytes (GB). There is no default database size limit for the Enterprise Edition. In order to have the full functionality of the Exchange database availability group (DAG) again, you must buy an Enterprise Edition license and apply it to the server.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/exchange-cannot-mount-database-larger-than-1024-gb

You also could test the workaround it provided.
If the answer is helpful please mark it as ANSWER

Comment: We dont have any issue with database size, the databases are mounted and the size limit is 2TB. Copy was working for last 5 years and suddenly stopped working last month so nothing wrong with licensing/limitation.

Comment: So your Exchange server is Enterprise Edition? It is so strange, since it can works under 500GB, it can prove that the DB had no issue. Did you get any related error in event log?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps to fix the issue:

Stop Microsoft Exchange Search service. then try to remove the copy completely and then again re-add, now restart Exchange Search service. it will fix the issue.

If it will not fix the issue then check no other seeding or incremental reseeding operations is not running for this database, and then Perform Following steps To Rebuild or Reseed the Search Catalog:-

1. Seed database copy without seeding the content index catalog

   Update-MailboxDatabaseCopy -Identity DB\MBX -DatabaseOnly
2. Seed the content index catalog for database copy without seeding the database file

   Update-MailboxDatabaseCopy -Identity DB\MBX -CatalogOnly
3. Run Following Script to Reset Index.

   ResetSearchIndex.ps1 script

Now [Check Exchange Database Copy Seed Status](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/54292.how-to-check-exchange-database-copy-seed-status.aspx).

Also check this link to [Monitor database availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/high-availability/manage-ha/monitor-dags?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchserver-2019).